# Azure Synapse replicated to Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, replication, azure-synapse

We have a Azure data warehouse db2(Azure Synapse) that will need to be consumed by read only users around the world, and we would like to replicate the needed objects from the data warehouse potentially to a cosmos DB. Is this possible, and if so what are the available options? (transactional, merege, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Synapse is mainly about getting your data to do analysis. I dont think it has a direct export option, the kind you have described above.

However, what you can do, is to use 'Azure Stream Analytics' and then you should be able to integrate/stream whatever you want to any destination you need, like an app or a database ands so on.

more details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-integrate-azure-stream-analytics

I think you can also pull the data into BI, and perhaps setup some kind of a automatic export from there.

more details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-visualize-with-power-bi